# When using MonoMac How instantiate NSDocument

Tags: monomac

Using MonoMac, I have a NSDocument-based application, but I'm needing to create a new NSDocument object when a button is clicked.

For example. I have in another Window I have a NSWindowController and I can do

```
Controller c = new Controller ();
c.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront (this);
```

thus causing the Window to be loaded that is tied to the controller.

With the NSDocument I guess the controller is built in?
So I'm expecting something like

```
MyNSDocument doc = new MyNSDocument ("Some Value ");
doc.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront (this);
```

Of course this doesn't work.

Additional info, for example when in the Application if you hit `Command + N`, then a new Document Window is loaded. This is cool and I basically need the same thing to happen, but when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "File" / "New" or `Control + N` invokes `newDocument:` on the application's shared document controller, which is the `menu.xib`'s First Responder.

To do the same programmatically, use `NSDocumentController.SharedDocumentController` to get the application's shared document controller, then invoke `NewDocument ()` on it (you can pass `null` as sender):

```
var controller = (NSDocumentController)NSDocumentController.SharedDocumentController;
controller.NewDocument (null);
```